# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The text and text data types are incompatible in the equals operator.' .net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a SQL Server Express database with this table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MovieGenreExcel" 
(
    "title" TEXT,
    "year" INTEGER,
    "summary" TEXT,
    "short_summary" TEXT,
    "genres" TEXT,
    "imdb_id" TEXT,
    "runtime" INTEGER,
    "youtube_trailer" TEXT,
    "movie_poster" TEXT,
    "director" TEXT,
    "writers" TEXT,
    "cast" TEXT,
    "rating" TEXT
);
```

In my ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API project, I would like to be able to find a film according to its `imbdID`.

Here is my `MovieGenreExcel` class which is the model class :

```
public partial class MovieGenreExcel
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
    public string? ShortSummary { get; set; }
    public string? Genres { get; set; }
    public string ImdbId { get; set; }
    public int? Runtime { get; set; }
    public string? YoutubeTrailer { get; set; }
    public string? MoviePoster { get; set; }
    public string? Director { get; set; }
    public string? Writers { get; set; }
    public string? Cast { get; set; }
    public string? Rating { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the method for retrieving a film according to its `imdbID`:

```
[HttpGet("getUnMovie", Name = "GetUnMovie")]
public dynamic getUnMovie()
{
    ProjetPolytechContext dbContext = new ProjetPolytechContext();
    string imdbIdTest = "tt1704292";

    var movie = dbContext.MovieGenreExcels.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ImdbId == imdbIdTest);

    return movie;
}
```

However I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The text and text data types are incompatible in the equals operator.'

I tried some things like :

```
var movie = dbContext.MovieGenreExcels.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ImdbId.Contains(imdbIdTest));
```

Error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The data type of argument text is not valid for argument 1 of function charindex.'

I looked at different threads before posting however none of the answers worked for me

Comment: The error is clear. The table types are bad. I'm pretty sure those other threads explain the problem. `TEXT` is a type that's obsolete for the last 20+ years, replaced by `varchar(max)`. Both are *only* meant for large (as in 2GB large) raw text data. You can't compare 2GB-sized fields, hence the errors. Use a proper type with a proper size instead, eg `nvarchar(20)`.

Comment: In short, change all `text` fields to `nvarchar(N)` with an appropriate size for each field. Don't use the non-Unicode type, `varchar()` because .NET *and YouTube* use Unicode. If you use `varchar` you'll lose or mangle any data that doesn't match your column's codepage

Comment: `image` is another obsolete type, replaced by `varbinary(max)`. How was this table created? No tool would use `text` or `image`. The documentation doesn't use these types, neither do any courses, books or tutorials released in the last 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

You are using BLOB data types rather than ones that are comparable. BLOB data types are stored in a different memory page with a pointer and aren't comparable. You only want to be returning this data, not looking up on it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MovieGenreExcel" 
(
    "title" nvarchar(256),
    "year" int,
    "summary" nvarchar(4000),
    "short_summary" nvarchar(512),
    "genres" id, // should be in own table with a relationship to this one as there are multiple
    "imdb_id" int,
    "runtime" int,
    "youtube_trailer" nvarchar(256),
    "movie_poster" image,
    "director" int, // FK to director table
    "writers" TEXT, // should be in own table with a relationship to this one as there are multiple
    "cast" // should be in own table with a relationship to this one as there are multiple,
    "rating" nvarchar(50) // however probably should be a FK to a lookup table
);
```

Read here for more info.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

Apart from your data types, as I have tried to highlight, your database isn't normalised to store one to many relationships. You also need to determine what is your primary key and what indexes you need to make lookups performant (this database usage scenario implies you are seeking to be be read performant).